# Excel formula to measure duration of breaks

Tags: excel, formula

I am working on a formula which will measure the duration of time my employees went on break.

The data I have:

```
NAME    LOGIN   LOGOUT  TYPE    DATE
JOHN    5:00 PM 6:00 PM BREAK   8/1/2018
MARK    6:15 PM 7:00 PM BREAK   8/1/2018
LUKE    5:05 PM 5:00 PM BREAK   8/1/2018
MARK    6:20 PM 9:00 PM LUNCH   8/1/2018
LUKE    6:20 PM 9:20 PM LUNCH   8/1/2018
JOHN    6:15 PM 9:00 PM LUNCH   8/1/2018
```

I want to measure the duration of their breaks. For instance, John logged out at 6:00 PM for his break and then logged in again at 6:15 PM. Unfortunately, the data I have are not in chronological order hence I need to lookup the specific values first depending on the date. Could you please provide me with a formula that will lookup John's logout time tagged "break" on 08/1/2018 and then subtract it from his login time on the same date to get the duration.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Or what ideas do you have for solving the problem? BTW, do you *really* want to track your employees? There are quite a few authors who advocate *not* doing what you say you want to do.

Comment: You have a typo in the first Luke,  The login happens after the logout.

Answer (score 2):

Use AGGREGATE to return the next login after the logout and subtract the current logout from that:

```
=IFERROR(AGGREGATE(15,6,($E$2:$E$7+$B$2:$B$7)/(($E$2:$E$7+$B$2:$B$7>E2+C2)*($A$2:$A$7=A2)),1)-(E2+C2),"No clock in")
```

[image]